# SQL Server CE "module could not be found" Crash

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, x86, sql-server-ce

We are getting following error message in one Windows XP - X86

```
Exception Source:      System.Data.SqlServerCe
Exception Type:        System.DllNotFoundException
Exception Message:     Unable to load DLL 'sqlceme35.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
Exception Target Site: DllAddRef
```

SQL Server CE installed and the application is compiled as X86 running OS is X86 as well.

Any idea why this might happen?

*Normally this works almost perfectly in most of the computers, but doesn't work on this one computer.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compile your application for 'Any CPU', then it will use the according x86/x64 libraries automatically.

Comment: There are some other problems awkward problems with compiling in Any CPU that's why we have to stick with x86. And why do you think this is going to solve the problem?

Comment: @dr. evil: I dont think, I know. I had this same issue with a personal application less than a month back.  Funny enough, I could not get it working when targeting x64 only :( You could probably compile a support library in 'Any CPU' mode maybe and call that as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

You must install the replication components on the device, this cab file contains the compaction dll: sqlce3x.repl.[platform].[processor].cab

Comment: It's a desktop application not compact, we are just using SQLCE in desktop instead of access.